# If using Rails, what search technology can use advanced "exclude"(-) and "must-have" ("text") features?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like a search function to be able to use advanced techniques like on Google - "-", "OR", -"word word1", and "quotes." How can I do that, or is it possibly standard for all? I will also consider Google search for enterprise, but it is ~$100 and I can probably build one for less.

I also would like keyword bolding (not highlighting). Immediate indexing would be nice too (unlike sites that say "your post will be live in 15 minutes." (Odesk, Craigslist.)

Of ElasticSearch, PG Search, Sphinx, Solr etc., which would be a good choice for my project? I am using Rails 4.0.8, Heroku, and PG.

I would also like to not have to use any Heroku plug-ins if possible, so maybe PG search would prevent that. My reasoning is that I'd rather be able to move off Heroku quickly, rather than tied down. If this is an incorrect assumption/worry please let me know.

Comment: Too many questions! these need to be separate questions, not all bundled into one like here. Also - for each question, you need to show us what effort you've put in to solving them, so we don't needlessly duplicate your own effort.

Comment: @CodeWalrus... your post came up on the "first posts" review queue. it was not my job to answer your questions... just to review whether your question met the usual Stack Overflow guidelines. Which I did. :)

Comment: @CodeWalrus, Taryn is just trying to remind you of the rules of SO. And he is right, proof is your question got put on hold. So please avoid this kind of comment

Comment: You'll notice that I'm not the only one to have felt this way (you'll notice your question has been closed as "too broad"), just the only one who took the time to explain why, and what you could do about it.

Comment: @TarynEast, This question is the opposite of broad. Your complaint of too many questions is like saying using Google Advanced search is "too specific." My questions were all related in *specifying* and *narrowing down* one specific search technology. And I found it. The answer was given in less than 10 lines of text, which is hardly "too long for this format."

Comment: Hi CodeWalrus. me and at least four other people disagree with you. Questions are often answered even if they don't fit the Stack Overflow guidelines. That should not be taken as meaning that you were right all along. Though perhaps you were narrowing to a particular topic... in which case it didn't come through in your wording - and you should work on that because it gave at least five people the wrong impression. In my next comment I'll explain the multiplicity of questions I saw in your wording above. I will totally paraphrase to get the point of what looks like many questions.

Comment: So I count 5 separate questions: 1) "how can I do a search that uses '-' or 'OR' " 2) "how can I do keyword bolding" 3) how can I do immediate indexing 4) which of these engines... would be a good choice 5) how can I do this without heroku plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elasticsearch and Solr are both based on Lucene and have very similar capabilities. Either would offer a wide variety of search syntax out of the box along with syntax highlighting and all the rest. Big comparison list here: http://solr-vs-elasticsearch.com

Sphinx leverages PG full-text search but keeps its own index

PG Search is a great way to get solid searching without external dependencies. It won't do much for your -foo +bar style searches AFAIK

Anything but PG Search would require a Heroku add-on. But if you move, Sphinx, Solr, and ElasticSearch can all come with you so that shouldn't be an issue.

I typically move straight to ElasticSearch if I need anything more than a trivial search tool.

Comment: EDIT - nvm I found it, did a ctl+f for "-" sign - http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html. ORIG MSSG - Hi John, thanks for the in-depth answer. Can you please link to a page or two that shows how to use the advanced syntax with ES? I found this one with Solr only, so far - http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-query-syntax.html